# How to add a custom paragraph format in CKEditor

Tags: drupal, ckeditor

In my project I have a requirement to remove the paragraph format like "Address" and "Formatted" from the drop down and to add a new custom format called "Links" which would be Arial, 14px, bold, red. Is it possible to add custom paragraph format in CKEditor?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [CKEDITOR.config.formatTags](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-format_tags) to specify some new formatting:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    format_tags: 'p;h2;h3;pre;links', // entries is displayed in "Paragraph format"
    format_links: {
        name: 'Links',
        element: 'span',
        styles: {
            color: 'red',
            'font-family': 'arial',
            'font-weight': 'bold'
        }
    }
} );
```

To know more about styles see how [CKEDITOR.styleSet](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.stylesSet) works. Also note that since CKEditor 4.1, removing styles from "Paragraph format" has an impact on [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter).

Comment: Where should I put this code ckeditor.config.js. i just put it on Custom JavaScript configuration but it's not working. Can you specify the location?

Comment: There are many places this can be set. Directly when creating an instance (as above), in `config.js` or in `customConfig`. See [docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_configuration) to know more.

Answer (score 6):

Since you're working with Drupal, `ckeditor.styles.js` is the file you're looking for, this will allow you to add/edit/remove entries in the Styles menu.

Comment out any entries you don't want, and use something like this to add a new paragraph format:

```
{ name : 'Links', element : 'p', attributes : { 'class' : 'links' } },
```

This will add the CSS class `links` to whatever paragraph you want, and you can define the class in your theme stylesheet. Make sure to define the class in `ckeditor.css` if you don't see the changes applied in the CKEditor instance.

Alternatively, you could also apply the inline styles directly:

```
{ name : 'Links', element : 'p', attributes : { 'style' : 'font: bold 14px Arial, sans-serif; color: red;' } },
```

But the first method is clearly more flexible/clean.

Make sure to clear your Drupal and/or browser cache if you don't see your changes show up immediately.

Comment: Does an answer that suggests to hack contrib modules really have 5 upvotes? Streuth.