# CKEditor: legend button for styling

Tags: ckeditor

In my ckeditor I would like to have a button like the bold button but then for the  tags. How can I do that?

Could not found anything about it..

---

What I've now is: (that do works)
style.js

```
CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add( 'default', [
    { name: 'Legend',           element: 'legend' },
}
```

When I press on the legend style nothing happens..

---

a nasty alternative that I use now is:

```
{
    name: 'Legend',
    element: 'span',
    styles: {
        'font-size': '17px',
        '-moz-border-bottom-colors': 'none',
        '-moz-border-left-colors': 'none',
        '-moz-border-right-colors': 'none',
        '-moz-border-top-colors': 'none',
        'border-color': '-moz-use-text-color -moz-use-text-color #E5E5E5',
        'border-image': 'none',
        'border-style': 'none none solid',
        'border-width': '0 0 1px',
        'color': '#333333',
        'display': 'block',
        'font-size': '21px',
        'line-height': '40px',
        'margin-bottom': '20px',
        'padding': '0',
        'width': '100%',
    }
},
```

But I still prefer the `<legend></legend>` Can somebody help me out?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do... And what have you already tried?

Comment: i'm trying to get something in my CKEditor for using <legend> in the editor

Answer (score 0):

[Styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808426/what-is-a-good-javascript-html-editor-for-adding-custom-html-elements/17812226#17812226). See my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18054351/add-buttons-for-custom-styles-to-ckeditor/18058824#18058824) and go ahead with similar code for your tag. You may also find [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230809/how-to-add-a-custom-paragraph-format-in-ckeditor/17231443#17231443) helpful, if you want to extend the built-in formatting combo.

Comment: Alright, almost got it. Now in the styles I have a list imported from styles.js, I added the next thing: `{ name: 'Legend',           element: 'legend' },` But when I use this in the editor nothing happens