# Drupal 7 blockquote in formatting with CKEditor

Tags: drupal-7, ckeditor

I'd like to add two forms of blockquote (one left & one right) to the "**formatting**" dropdown menu (not styles) in CKEditor in Drupal 7. Right now I only get options like "normal," "heading 2," etc.

If the editor selects "block quote right," for example from the dropdown it would wrap the text so that the end result would be something like this:

```
<blockquote class="blockquote-right"> Some text </blockquote>
```

How can that be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a custom paragraph format in CKEditor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230809/how-to-add-a-custom-paragraph-format-in-ckeditor)

Comment: That seems like it should work, but it doesn't. The formatting stays the same when I put that code into ckeditor.config.js

Comment: Add a jsfiddle of your code with the problem